# Splitting one servlet class to servlet and DAO class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am requesting information from JSP and putting them to database via Java Servlet. I have this kind of (simplified) Java Servlet.

```
protected void doPost(//parameters etc.){

String brand = request.getParameter("brand");
String model = request.getParameter("model");
CarBean newCar = new CarBean(brand, model);

try {
          Connection con = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
          PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Cars (brand, model)"
          + "VALUES (?, ?)";              
          ps.setString(1, newCar.getBrand());
          ps.setString(2, newCar.getModel());
          ps.executeUpdate();
          ps.close();
} catch ... {
}
```

Everything is working correctly, but now I want to separate this database connection to it's own class. I want to do a class where is just three methods (add, delete, edit) for database.

Can I use a newCar object as a parameter somehow in a class which is in different package? I've done this, but this isn't working.

```
public class DAO{

public void addCar(CarBean newCar) throws ServletException {
 try {
         Connection con = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
         PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Cars (brand, model)"
         + "VALUES (?, ?)";
         ps.setString(1, newCar.getBrand());
         ps.setString(2, newCar.getModel());
         ps.executeUpdate();
         ps.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
}

...
public void deleteCar ...
public void editCar ...
```

and then I just call addCar from Servlet like this:

```
protected void doPost(//parameters etc.){

String brand = request.getParameter("brand");
String model = request.getParameter("model");
CarBean newCar = new CarBean(brand, model);
addCar(newCar);
```

It's saying

```
cannot find symbol, symbol: method addCar(CarBean), location: class MainServlet
```

and offers to make method addCar to this servlet, but that can't be right. That addCar method have to be in DAO class (which is in Database folder).

I don't know if this is quite confusing? How to move that try-catch which is doing data transferring to another class?

Comment: What do you mean by *it's not working*? Which kind of error or exception are you getting?

Comment: What Error you are getting ?

Comment: Your example seems correct, using a different package is not a problem but you need to import it in the Servlet

Comment: Servlet is saying "cannot find symbol, symbol: method addCar(CarBean), location: class MainServlet". It's offering to make "method addCar(Bean.CarBean) in Servlets.MainServlet", but that can't be right? To clarify; "Bean" and "Servlets" are folders, in "Bean" there is CarBean class and in "Servlets" there is MainServlet servlet. Now I have third folder which is "Database" and there is that DAO class.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the *new* code i.e. the code after your refactoring **below** your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that it is looking for a method called `addCar` on the MainServlet class (and of course it isn't finding it).

You need to specify where it should look for the addCar method. The servlet needs to have a reference to a DAO object and the servlet code needs to call the method on the DAO object.

Assuming this DAO has no state, you can make an instance variable for it in the servlet, like:

```
private Database.DAO dao = new Database.DAO();
```

and call addCar on it from the doPost method:

```
dao.addCar(newCar);
```